# Passports stapled together

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, vfs-global, student-visas

My old Indian passports and new one are stapled together with no harm done at all to any of them. Will it be a problem when I submit it to VFS Global for French student Visa? I hope they won't refuse to accept it?

The old passports don't have current Visas, only expired ones.

I believe the passport authorities stapled it. Will un-stapling be a good choice? There'd be small holes, or should I keep it as it is?

Comment: Does your old passport have any current visas in it?

Comment: Who stapled your passports together?

Comment: can you just... unstaple them and make the problem go away?

Comment: The old passports dont have current Visa but expired ones.

Comment: The passport authorities stapled it iguess and will unstapling be a good choice? There'd be small holes or should I keep it as it is?

Comment: You guess?  You don't know for sure who stapled them together?

Answer (score 4):

When we submit old and new passports for visa, sometimes they pin them together to avoid losing one passport.

Once you receive it, it's safe to carefully unstaple them, as you only have to provide your latest one to immigration officials (unless your visa is in the old one, which means you should carry both).